# Google api php client code not return refresh token

Tags: javascript, php, google-api-php-client, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have been trying to get refresh token from google api using javascript google client " code " that google return from client side. It returns me the code which i send to the server side. Now from server side i am sending the code to get the refresh token and access token using **using google-api-php-client** with this call :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```

While i use the same code from google playground i get the response with refresh token as well but i do not get it from my own server..
This is the code

```
public function getRefreshToken($code)
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(config('services.google.client_id'));
    $client->setClientSecret(config('services.google.client_secret'));
    $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
    $client->setScopes(config('services.google.scopes'));
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
    dd($client->authenticate($code));
    dd($client->getRefreshToken());
    return ;
}
```

I have set access type to offline as mentioned in some answers but still i get the response with our refresh token.. this is the response

```
access_token :"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
created:1510242052
expires_in:3598
id_token:"xxxxxxxx"
token_type:"Bearer"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your php code looks fine to me.  I suspect your front end javascript, specifically the link to google that it builds, may be to blame.  Whether the authorization_code produces a refresh token when redeemed is partially dependent on what parameters are included in the initial link to Google.

As detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468307/2999566), the javascript client library uses "client side flow". Normally in a front end app you'd specify `response_type=token`, but if you specify `response_type=code`, instead, you'll get a `code` back. But when redeemed, that `code` will not produce a refresh token.

For example, [a link built by a front end javascript library](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#redirecting) might look like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=7xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback.php&response_type=code&scope=profile
```

Your back end can redeem the `code` that comes back, but the response will not include a refresh token.  This is by design.

One way to get a `code` that is eligible for refresh tokens, would be to use the back end PHP client library to build the link, rather than the javascript client library.  `$client->createAuthUrl()` will build a link like this:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&**access_type=offline**&client_id=7xxxxxxxxxx-hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Foauth2callback.php&state&scope=profile&**approval_prompt=force**

[This toy example](https://github.com/mikepatrick/php-google-calendar) builds the link this way and does receive refresh tokens.

Note the addition of `access_type=offine` and `approval_prompt=force`.  After successful authentication, the redirect in this case includes a `code` that *does* provide a refresh token when redeemed.

The OAuth 2.0 playground builds an initial link that contains `access_type=offline` and `prompt=consent`, which also creates a code that is redeemable for a refresh token.

If this isn't helpful, perhaps you could update the question with the link to google that your front end is building?  (With client id redacted, of course)

Comment: I tried what you asked me to do i am getting an " ORIGIN PARAMETER REQUIRED " error..

Comment: Are you now getting a refresh token back?  When do you get this error -  When you first go to Google?  When you call `authenticate()`?  When you try to actually use the access_token?    This error sounds like a Maps API error.... is that what you're trying to consume?

Comment: I have two things to say here.

1. First this is not mentioned in any of the answers here on stack over flow then why i had to give bounty on this question ?  it wasnt answered anywhere still nobody gave attention to this question.

2. There is nothing like this mentioned anywhere in GOOGLE DOCUMENTS . WHY IS THAT SO ?

Comment: The question does not specify on what step you are not getting response. The code as said in the answer is fine. What matters is the token. Which token you are passing to refresh it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241213/how-to-refresh-token-with-google-api-client link has detailed accepted answers. If you still did not get it worked, please let me know with your test data.