# Getting access and refresh token for google api using firebase and angular fire auth login

Tags: angular, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am using angular fire auth and firebase API for performing authentication. I am getting access token for google API for the first time I log in, but I am not getting a refresh token for it. So can anyone guide on how should I get refresh token for refreshing access token when it expires (does Rest API exists)?

Comment: This might help but i dont know enough about angular to know.  It would help if you would edit your question and include your code https://stackoverflow.com/q/24454137/1841839

Comment: Actually I want to access google API's on backend. Hence I want a rest API which will give me refresh token.

Comment: Rest APIs dont return refresh tokens.  Authentication servers return refresh tokens you need to authenticate in order to get a refresh token even back end.

Comment: It sounds like what you're saying is that once the user logs into your client, you want them to stay logged in. So you need to get a valid auth token after the first expires while the user is still at the keyboard, but without interrupting them to log in again. Does that sound about right?

Comment: @Prisoner yeah thats right. I don't want users to log in again after access token expires. I have google's ID Token and access token. I also have firebase's Refresh token and ID token.

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to get the refresh token on user first sign in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the refresh token **only the first time you login using your app**. To see the refresh token again revoke access to that app from your [manage google account setting,](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and sign in again.

Comment: How do you get the refresh token when you login the first time? I can see an access token but I am not able to see any refresh token