# Google Oauth2 invalid_grant error while trying to refresh an access token

Tags: curl, google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

**Scenario**

I am trying to generate a Google OAuth2 access token with a supplied refresh token. The refresh token is obtain from the client side Javascript SDK, using the offline access method as mentioned in the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49842793/16341841

The refresh token that's obtained is sent to the backend server, and the backend server tries to get a new access token using this refresh token whenever required. The API endpoint along with the request params being used for the same is:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<my_client_id> \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<my_client_secret>' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=<refresh_token_sent_by_frontend>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token'
```

**Result (Error)**

I receive the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

**What I have already tried**

I have tried all applicable (literally all) solutions mentioned in the following link and internal links mentioned in the answers as well:
[invalid_grant trying to get oAuth token from google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576386/invalid-grant-trying-to-get-oauth-token-from-google)

**Notes**

1. The client id and client secret are the exact same on both frontend and backend.
2. Whenever I generate a refresh token via Postman using OAuth2 APIs, I don't face any issues at all with token refresh using the same request as mentioned above. So I am assuming that I am doing the token refresh correctly on the backend.

What else could I be possibly missing? Would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2):

You are building the request wrong.  Its a url string.

```
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

[Understanding Google OAuth 2.0 with curl](https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w)